# MySQL indexing with a two columns, one of which is a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, indexing

I have table T1 where col A is primary key and col B is a foreign key which is a primary key in table T2. I want to create an index in T1, a composite one as (B,A). But MySQL is allowing me to create the index as (A,B) only. Is it because col B is a foreign key ?? Please explain

Comment: Could you please post the scripts you are using?

Comment: And the error that you get...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, b INT NOT NULL REFERENCES t2(id)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE INDEX ix_t1_b_a ON t1 (b, a);
```

Though `InnoDB` does include clustered key as a row pointer in the indexes, there is nothing that prevents adding the field explicitly and sometimes it is required to optimize some queries.

Please check your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does not have sense.
You are trying to build a composite index using a column which is already unique (Primary key are unique).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using InnoDB as the storage engine, a index on column B alone will include column A (the primary key)

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/10/03/mysql-optimizer-and-innodb-primary-key/

Comment: in my case, actually, both col A and B are primary keys and COL B is also a foreign key . so mysql gives u a default index as composite(A,B). but I want (b,a)

Comment: @patruni so create a index on B and it will include - behind the scene - column A also. (since A is the left most column in the primary key index)

Comment: @Scrum Meister : But I don't need to create an index on B as by default mysql gives me an index on it since its a foreign key. Do you mean to say that this index includes A also behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB clusters the data using the primary key. If you don't define the primary key, InnoDB will try to use a unique non-nullable index instead.This will ensure that rows are inserted in sequential order and will offer better performance for joins using primary keys. But in my question, I said that in table T1 the PK is col A and col B is a foreign key which is not unique in T1. So, if I set pk as (A,B) , automatically mysql will index it as primary index. If you try to change the index as (B,A) , since B is not unique, InnoDB cannot index it as it uses cluster indexing. So, it will throw error.